# How does the length of the plaintext affect the cipher strength?

Tags: block-cipher, brute-force-attack

Let the block length 64-bit, 256-bit key, cipher text accordingly - 64 bits. What is the strength of the block cipher, if any unknown attacks, which could reduce its strength. We can only brute force.

Let $M=\{0,1\}^{64}$ be the plaintext space, $C=\{0,1\}^{64}$ be the  ciphertext space and $K=\{0,1\}^{256}$ be the keyspace. Then:

$\forall m\in M\ \exists\ k_1,\dots,k_n\in K \colon E(m,k_1)=\dots=E(m,k_n)=c$.

That is, for fixed message and some keys.

How can we use this fact to reduce the cost of a brute force attack?

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question. $\;$

Comment: You seem to be missing my point. $\:$ Your second sentence should have something corresponding to $\hspace{.56 in}$ the last part of "if x, which is likely, then y", although it doesn't actually need to use the word "then". $\hspace{.42 in}$ "What is the strength of the block cipher, if any unknown attacks, which could reduce its strength", $\:$ ... . $\hspace{.38 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer I am wondering, why do you always use LaTeX code to format your comments? They tend to display rather oddly for me.

Comment: I try to line-up the lines and space-out the sentences. $\;$ (For some reason, it occasionally changes how they render a few minutes after I post them.) $\;\;\;$

Comment: Strength - cryptographic resistance of ciphers

Comment: @NiceTheo: I'm having trouble understanding your question - Is my edit the correct interpretation of it? If not, would you mind clarifying what is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still a little unsure what your question is, but I'll try and answer what I think you're asking. If it isn't, please clarify your question or comment below.

Let us assume that $E_k$ is an ideal block cipher$^{[1]}$, and so acts like a random permutation of $2^{64}$ elements.

> Given $(m,c)\in M\times C$ find $k\in K$ such that $E(m,k)=c$. How long will this take?

In total there are $2^{64}!$ permutations of $2^{64}$ elements, but we are only interested in the ones that map $m$ to $c$. As such, we are actually looking at how many ways there are to permute the remaining elements, so there are $(2^{64}-1)!$ permutations.
 So, of the $2^{64}!$ permutations we expect $(2^{64}-1)!$ will map $m\to c$, meaning we expect that
$\frac{(2^{64}-1)!}{2^{64}!}=2^{-64}$ of keys will be suitable. So, it should take around $2^{64}$ key guesses.

> Given $(m,c)\in M\times C$, how many $k\in K$ are there such that $E(m,k)=c$

Since there are $2^{256}$ keys, and we expect to find a suitable $k$ with probability $2^{-64}$ trials, we expect there to be $2^{256-64}=2^{192}$ possible keys.

> So, how many trials should it take to find the correct key?

The important thing to notice here is that, no matter how many trials you run, with just one plaintext-ciphertext pair there will still be lots of false positives, and you will have no way of knowing which is correct. The obvious solution to this is to take more $(m,c)$ pairs, but how many? Suppose we have $n$ distinct $(m,c)$-pairs. Then, a false-positive key must fix these $n$ points, leaving it a permutation of $|M|-n$ points. Following the same logic as above, that means the probability of hitting a false-positive key is
$$P = \frac{(2^{64}-m)!}{2^{64}!}
    = \frac{1}{2^{64}\times (2^{64}-1)\times\cdots\times(2^{64}-m+1)}
$$
We want $P\ll2^{256}$, since at this point we can reasonably assume that even in all $2^{256}$ keys there isn't a false positive. As such, $5$ pairs would be sufficient.

I leave it to the reader to consider how long such an attack would take$^{[2]}$.

---

1. The assumption on $E_k$ is an ideal cipher is important. For example, the function given below certainly cannot be modelled as a random permutation, but finding a preimage pair $(m,k)$ is trivial for any $c$.
   $$E(m,k)=\begin{cases}
     m & k=0
   \\0 & k\neq0 
   \end{cases}$$
2. Hint: If $E(m_1,k)\neq c_1$, then we do not need to calculate $E(m_2,k)\stackrel{?}{=}c_2$. So, how many times do we calculate $E(m_2,k)$? How about $E(m_3,k)\ \dots$

Comment: Please feel free to correct minor errors - if you find a major one you're welcome to put a big warning at the top of the answer. I won't be offended and it should stop anyone else following my errors!

Comment: My question isn't so clear, but your answer exactly show what I want.